# Is there a way for a systemd service to find out a device path and restart if it changes?

Tags: systemd, usb-device

I'm running a daemon that needs a path to a device when it starts. This device is connected to the USB bus but sometimes drops off the USB and reconnects again (either a loose connector or crashing hardware, have not found the problem yet), and but then the device gets another name, say, `/dev/ttyACM0` becomes `/dev/ttyACM1`.

It's a virtual serial port that spits out NMEA data from an AIS receiver (Quark-elec QK-A022 for the interested).

I'm pretty sure only one device will ever be connected at the same time to the USB.

Is there a way to start/restart a service with systemd when a specific kind of device is inserted in the system? I noticed `systemctl list-units --type=device` which lists the device so I'm hopeful, but every example I've found thus far is based on explicitly starting servicename@device.

```
root@ais:/home/pi# systemctl list-units --type=device | fgrep STM
sys-devices-platform-soc-3f980000.usb-usb1-1\x2d1-1\x2d1.2-1\x2d1.2:1.0-tty-ttyACM1.device                      loaded active plugged STM32F407
```

I'm pretty sure only one device will ever be connected at the same time to the USB.

Comment: While I do not have a precise answer, I would recommend to check `man systemd.service` or any other `systemd.*` man pages.  Other than that, I would possibly have a script run periodically (or through `inotifywait`) to check on the status and then have that script restart the systemd item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These days the canonical way to run a daemon when a device is plugged in seems to be to create a systemd Unit for the daemon, and add a udev entry for the device referring to this Unit.  For example, create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-my.rules` with the line

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyACM*", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="myacm@%k.service"
```

and a file `/etc/systemd/system/myacm@.service` with

```
[Unit]
Description=my serial daemon for ttyACM0
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/myscript %i
```

You may need `sudo udevadm control --reload` and `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`. When you plug in your device your script should be run with the parameter `ttyACM0` if that is its name. Check the log files for errors.

See `man 7 daemon` section *New-Style Daemons* and *Device-Based Activation*, as well as `man systemd.device`.

Comment: I had to reboot but to get it working but other then that this works. What is the difference between a file in /etc/systemd and /lib/systemd? And, another question perhaps, how do you stop the script if the device is ejected again? I've found ACTION='remove', RUN+='pkill...' but that seems rather unelegant.

Comment: See `man file-hierarchy`. `/etc/` is for the local administrator to use.

Comment: This answer gives a great overview of hooking udev rules to systemd scripts, but for an actual Arduino, no variation of KERNEL rules worked at all for me. It only worked for me if I matched on `SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ` (optionally with specific `ATTRS{idVendor}` and `ATTRS{idProduct}`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can do that within systemd but you could use udev for restarting / reloading the service if it detects a device change.